# VBscript to get the properties of event from event ID

Tags: security, events, vbscript

I want to know if it is possible to get the IP of machine, logged on user, hostname from event id 4624 using vbscript?

I want a vbscript which takes out this information:[image: Event properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You need to query events with the ID 4624 from the eventlog and then parse name, IP address and port out of the message string, e.g. with a regular expression:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "Network Information:\s+" & _
             "Workstation Name:\s*(.*?)\s+" & _
             "Source Network Address:\s*(.*?)\s+" & _
             "Source Port:\s*(\d+)"

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE EventCode=4624"
For Each evt In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  For Each m In re.Execute(evt.Message)
    hostname = m.SubMatches(0)
    address  = m.SubMatches(1)
    port     = m.SubMatches(2)
  Next
  WScript.Echo hostname & " [" & address & ":" & port & "]"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it sounds like you're looking for [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/28c7d7bc-29da-485c-9ca0-b23f2d42205c/vbscript-extract-data-from-windows-event-log). In it, the author outlines a very thorough approach but the key bit is:

```
Function ProcessScript
   Dim hostName, logName, startDateTime, endDateTime
   Dim events, eventNumbers, i
   hostName      = wshNetwork.ComputerName
   logName       = "Security"
   eventNumbers  = Array("672") ' This is a comma-delimited list of events. You would include 4212 here
   startDateTime = DateAdd("n", -120, Now)
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   'Query the event log for the eventID's within the specified event log name and date range.
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   If Not QueryEventLog(events, hostName, logName, eventNumbers, startDateTime) Then
      Exit Function
   End If

End Function
```

This function calls into QueryEventLog, which does the heavy lifting:

```
Function QueryEventLog(results, hostName, logName, eventNumbers, startDateTime)
   Dim wmiDateTime, wmi, query, eventItems, eventItem
   Dim timeWritten, eventDate, eventTime, description
   Dim eventsDict, eventInfo, errorCount, i
   QueryEventLog = False
   errorCount    = 0
   If Not IsArray(eventNumbers) Then
      eventNumbers = Array(eventNumbers)
   End If
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   'Construct part of the WMI Query to account for searching multiple eventID's
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   query = "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = " & SQ(logName) & " And (EventCode = "
   For i = 0 To UBound(eventNumbers)
      query = query & SQ(eventNumbers(i)) & " Or EventCode = "
   Next
   On Error Resume Next
      Set eventsDict = NewDictionary
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         LogError "Creating Dictionary Object"
         Exit Function
      End If
      Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & hostName & "\root\cimv2")
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         LogError "Creating WMI Object to connect to " & DQ(hostName)
         Exit Function
      End If
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      'Create the "SWbemDateTime" Object for converting WMI Date formats. Supported in Windows Server 2003 & Windows XP.
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Set wmiDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         LogError "Creating " & DQ("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime") & " object"
         Exit Function
      End If
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      'Build the WQL query and execute it.
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      wmiDateTime.SetVarDate startDateTime, True
      query          = Left(query, InStrRev(query, "'")) & ") And (TimeWritten >= " & SQ(wmiDateTime.Value) & ")"
      Set eventItems = wmi.ExecQuery(query)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         LogError "Executing WMI Query " & DQ(query)
         Exit Function
      End If
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      'Convert the property values of Each event found to a comma seperated string and add it to the dictionary.
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      For Each eventItem In eventItems
         Do
            timeWritten = ""
            eventDate   = ""
            eventTime   = ""
            eventInfo   = ""
            timeWritten = ConvertWMIDateTime(eventItem.TimeWritten)
            eventDate   = FormatDateTime(timeWritten, vbShortDate)
            eventTime   = FormatDateTime(timeWritten, vbLongTime)
            eventInfo   = eventDate                          & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventTime              & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.SourceName   & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.Type         & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.Category     & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.EventCode    & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.User         & ","
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & eventItem.ComputerName & ","
            description = eventItem.Message
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Ensure the event description is not blank.
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            If IsNull(description) Then
               description = "The event description cannot be found."
            End If
            description = Replace(description, vbCrLf, " ")
            eventInfo   = eventInfo & description
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Check if any errors occurred enumerating the event Information
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
               LogError "Enumerating Event Properties from the " & DQ(logName) & " event log on " & DQ(hostName)
               errorCount = errorCount + 1
               Err.Clear
               Exit Do
            End If
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Remove all Tabs and spaces.
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            eventInfo = Trim(Replace(eventInfo, vbTab, " "))
            Do While InStr(1, eventInfo, "  ", vbTextCompare) <> 0
               eventInfo = Replace(eventInfo, "  ", " ")
            Loop
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Add the Event Information to the Dictionary object if it doesn't exist.
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            If Not eventsDict.Exists(eventInfo) Then
               eventsDict(eventsDict.Count) = eventInfo
            End If
         Loop Until True
      Next
   On Error Goto 0
   If errorCount <> 0 Then
      Exit Function
   End If
   results       = eventsDict.Items
   QueryEventLog = True
End Function
```

The rest is detailed in that article, but basically just concerns itself with writing the results to a file and adding some nice user interactions around the execution.